# jQuery toggle colors of element on hover

Tags: jquery, css, colors, hover

I have two words within a div. One of the words is black, the other grey. When I hover over the words, I'd like the colors to swap over and then back again when I hover out.

So far here is my html markup:

```
<div class="splash_logo">
    <span class="paul">paul</span><span class="jones">jones.</span>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.splash_logo {
position:relative;
font-family: Helvetica,Helvetica Neue,Arial,sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:100px;
float:right;
margin-top:110px;
}
span.paul {
color:#222222;
}
span.jones {
color:#dedede;
}
```

And finally my jquery for the hover event:

```
$(".splash_logo").hover(function(){
    $('span.paul').css("color", "#dedede");
    $('span.jones').css("color", "#222222");
});
```

This will change the colours when I hover over, however, how can I get them to change back when I hover out?

Comment: you could do this with just CSS `:hover`, no need for the JS.

Comment: If you just have to do it with jQuery, this is how -> **http://jsfiddle.net/aLk7x0k1/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [:hover - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

[DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/Lye7afx4/1/)

```
span.paul:hover {
color:#dedede;
}
span.jones:hover {
color:#222222;
}
```

Update:

```
.splash_logo:hover span.paul {
color:#dedede;
}
.splash_logo:hover span.jones {
color:#222222;
}
```

[DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/Lye7afx4/3/)

Comment: OK, but how do I do this so when you hover over .splash_logo div, both colours change?

Comment: @SamSkirrow - like this -> `.splash_logo:hover .paul { color:#dedede; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a second function into the call to hover(), which will get executed when the mouse moves out of the div. So you probably want something like this:

```
$(".splash_logo").hover(function(){
    $('span.paul').css("color", "#dedede");
    $('span.jones').css("color", "#222222");
}, 
function(){
    $('span.paul').css("color", "#222222");
    $('span.jones').css("color", "#dedede");
});
```

For more info, check the API docs: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

EDIT: what you want to do is probably better achieved using CSS, as other people have already suggested in their answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to add an event handler for that span.

```
$(".splash_logo").on("mouseenter", function(){
     $('span.paul').css("color", "#dedede");
     $('span.jones').css("color", "#222222");
});

$(".splash_logo").on("mouseleave", function(){
     $('span.paul').css("color", "red");
     $('span.jones').css("color", "green");
});
```

Or something like this:

```
$(".splash_logo").mouseenter(function(){
   //your code here
}).mouseleave(function(){
   //your code here
});
```

Or using a css method like in kougiland answer.

You can view a list of all mouse events [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use css `:hover` pseudo selector as follows:

```
.splash_logo:hover .paul{
  color:#dedede;
}
.splash_logo:hover .jones {
  color:#222222;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's **.hover()** can take two functions as arguments:

```
$("selector").hover(function1, function2);
```

Function1 gets called when the mouse enters the element, function2 is called on mouseleave = when hover has ended.